# Chrome extension chrome.tabs.executeScript no working

Tags: javascript, html

It throws me
Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.executeScript(optional integer tabId, extensionTypes.InjectDetails details, optional function callback): No matching signature.
this error.

Here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body style="width: 300px">
        <button id="draw">Draw</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

popup.js

```
    function execute() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            {file: 'p5.js'},
            {file: 'sketch.js'}
        ); 
    }
      
    document.getElementById('draw').addEventListener('click', execute);
```

Answer (score 0):

No matching signature should mean invalid arguments. executeScript only lets you pass only one file at a time. You can change your code to this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            {file: 'p5.js'}
        ); 
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            {file: 'sketch.js'}
        );
```